# JAVA: variable taking different values

Tags: java

```
public class Agn {
    int y=33;

    public static void main(String[] args){

       Agn a = new Agn();
       a.disp();
       System.out.println(a.y);
    }

    void disp (){
       Agn a = new Agn();
       y=44;
       System.out.println(a.y); 
       System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

In the above code, `System.out.println(a.y)` prints **44** and `System.out.println(y)` prints **33**. 
The same statement `System.out.println(a.y)` when used in the main method prints **44**. why is there a difference? Shouldn't it be **44** always?

Comment: You should look into scope of variables!

Comment: Why are you creating a **`new`** instance of `Agn` in `disp()`? Why would `this.y` be `a.y`? (the `this` is implicit in your code)

Comment: Unrelated: look into your naming. There is no point in abbreviating a method name to disp() - why not call it `printToConsole()` for example. And what is `Agn` supposed to mean?! In other words: use names that communicate **meaning** to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Object `a` in `disp()` is a different object (don't be disguised by same alias `a` and tbh I don't know why did you make it - @ElliottFrisch's comment explains it pretty well) and hence you are getting different values. Modify your `disp()` so it would be something like:

```
class Agn
{
    int y = 33;
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        Agn a = new Agn();
        System.out.println(a.y);
       a.disp();
       System.out.println(a.y);
    }

void disp (){

   y=44;
   //System.out.println(a.y); 
   System.out.println(y);
}
}
```

[Output would be:](https://www.ideone.com/aH8BTB)

**33
44
44**

as anticipated by you

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Agn {
int y=33;

public static void main(String[] args){

   Agn a = new Agn();//create local  object in main method  effect on  instance variable
   a.disp();
   System.out.println(a.y);
}

void disp (){
   Agn a = new Agn();//create local object not effect on  instance variable
   y=44; //you can mark y variable as static 
         //then you get output same
   System.out.println(a.y);  
   System.out.println(y);

   Agn a2 = new Agn(); // same create local object not effect on  instance variable 
   System.out.println(a2.y);//same o/p
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
Agn a = new Agn();
y=44;
```

The later is the same as: `this.y = 44`

In other words: there are **two** `Agn` objects in your code. The one that the `main()` method created - and **another** one that the `disp()` method created. Two objects, thus **two** different `y` fields - which can hold different content.

That is all there is to this.